# How to get resource quotas for every resource in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota, resources

I have set up few resources in my project on Google Cloud Platform.
I was looking for the resource quotas that is applicable for all the resources under a project.
As per the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas, running the following commands will provide the region wise and project wise quotas:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject
gcloud compute regions describe [REGION]
```

But the resources listed from these are limited and does not contain specific ones.
For instance, I want to know the quotas for the load balancers, storage buckets, VMs, NAT, Firewall  etc.
Is there any other way to specifically get quotas for every resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) in the Google Cloud Console sound like what you are looking for. This page will allow you to view quotas for [all resources in your project](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_project_quotas). The console page will show you what state your current quota use is for any given resource associated to your project. The documentation for each quota is broken down into relevant sections on the Google Public Docs, for example: [Load balancing resource quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas). Searching the quota name referenced on the Console quotas page (for a given quota) on the public docs, will provide the relevant additional documentation.